# Tabulator.js 5.2 datetime formatter with luxon.js, how to configure inputFormat for unix timestamps

Tags: tabulator, luxon

I have a dataset with unix timestamp and want to display a readable date. Which inputFormat do I have to configure (using tabulator 5.2)?

I am switching from tabulator 4.9 to 5.2, which also changes the library used for the `formatter:"datetime"` from moment.js to luxon.js. With moment.js the formatterParams below worked.

```
 formatterParams:{
            inputFormat:"unix",
            outputFormat:"DD/MM/YY HH:mm",
            invalidPlaceholder:"(invalid date)"
}
```

With the luxon.js this doesn't work and I don't know which inputFormat to configure.

**EDIT:**

Relevant parts of the table

```
var event_table = new Tabulator("#events-table", {
    height: "750",
    layout: "fitDataTable",
    movableRows: true,
    ajaxURL: [],
    columns: [
        { rowHandle: true, formatter: "handle", headerSort: false, frozen: true, width: 30, minWidth: 30 },
        {
            title: "Time", field: "timestamp", headerFilter: "input", formatter: "datetime", formatterParams: {
                inputFormat: "unix",
                outputFormat: "DD/MM/YY HH:mm",
                invalidPlaceholder: "(invalid date)"
            }
        },
        { title: "Typ", field: "type", headerFilter: "list", headerFilterParams: { values: true } }
    ]
});
```

data:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1655845814046,
        "type": "weight"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1655845931252,
        "type": "weight"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1655877784130,
        "type": "amount"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1655877828127,
        "type": "weight"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you include some sample data of your table? How does the input dates look like?

Comment: I've edited the post and added some data

Comment: I encountered similar issues but with **datetimediff** have reverted to using `moment` in a custom formatter.  https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3957 for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `"unix"` is not *"officially"* supported by Tabulator 4.9, I don't see it mentioned in the [DateTime built-in formatters](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-builtin).

It works because tabulator uses [`var newDatetime = moment(value, inputFormat);`](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/4.9.3/src/js/modules/format.js#L349) to parse cell value. So tabulator uses [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) that is *is very forgiving*, in your case it parse correctly the unix timestamp since the `"unix"` string used as  format token contains the `x` that represents the token for *Unix ms timestamp*.

---

Luxon has no counterpart for moment `x`, you should use [`DateTime.fromMillis`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefrommillis) to [parse Unix timestamps](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=unix-timestamps). There seems to be no way to use `DateTime.fromMillis` using [DateTime formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/format#formatter-datetime) of version 5.2 of tabulator (see [its code](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/5.2.7/src/js/modules/Format/defaults/formatters/datetime.js)).

You can instead use a [custom formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/format#format-custom):

> As well as the built-in formatters you can define a formatter using a custom formatter function.
>
> The formatter function accepts two arguments, the [CellComponent](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/components#component-cell) for the cell being formatted and the `formatterParams` option from the column definition.
>
> The function must return the contents of the cell, either the text value of the cell, valid HTML or a DOM node.

Example:

```js
var tabledata = [{
    "timestamp": 1655845814046,
    "type": "weight"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1655845931252,
    "type": "weight"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1655877784130,
    "type": "amount"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1655877828127,
    "type": "weight"
  }
];

var event_table = new Tabulator("#events-table", {
  data: tabledata,
  height: "750",
  layout: "fitDataTable",
  //movableRows: true,
  //ajaxURL: [],
  columns: [{
      rowHandle: true,
      formatter: "handle",
      headerSort: false,
      frozen: true,
      width: 30,
      minWidth: 30
    },
    {
      title: "Time",
      field: "timestamp",
      headerFilter: "input",
      formatter: function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        try {
          let dt = luxon.DateTime.fromMillis(cell.getValue());
          return dt.toFormat(formatterParams.outputFormat);
        } catch (error) {
          return formatterParams.invalidPlaceholder;
        }
      },
      formatterParams: {
        outputFormat: "dd/MM/yy HH:mm",
        invalidPlaceholder: "(invalid date)"
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Typ",
      field: "type",
      headerFilter: "list",
      headerFilterParams: {
        values: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.4.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>

<div id="events-table"></div>
```